# .doc / .docx problem to display in browser

Tags: html, web, browser, docx, .doc

I am trying to find a solution for a website that I made so that the word documents will not download automatically anymore, but that they display directly in a new page in the browser when I click them.
Can someone help me?? How can I do that in HTML?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches you can take for this:

- Ensure that all visitors to your site have a browser extension which can display Word documents. (This isn't something you can control for a typical website but might be an option for a company Intranet)
- Convert the Word documents to a format that the browser can display (i.e. HTML). You could do this manually or with code (which could be client-side or server-side). The Word document formats are notoriously complex so you would need to find a third party library that could do this for you.